# Scatterplot3d - resizing the polygon/plane

Tags: r, arguments, polygon

This is an example using the data set `College` from ISLR:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(ISLR)
attach(College)

s3d <- scatterplot3d(x=Top10perc, y=S.F.Ratio, z=PhD)
my.lm <- lm(Top10perc ~ S.F.Ratio + PhD)
plane <- s3d$plane3d(my.lm, lty.box = "solid", draw_polygon = TRUE)
```

[image: The resulting plot]

I want to increase the size of the gray polygon (plane). From scatterplot3d documentation:

> The arguments `draw_lines` and `draw_polygon` allow  for  choosing  whether  to  represent  the  plane  via  line  segments  or  as  a solid surface, respectively.  The list in `polygon_args` collects arguments to be passed to the underlying polygon call that draws a solid (or transparent) plane if `draw_polygon=TRUE`.

The `polygon` function:

> `polygon(x, y = NULL, density = NULL, angle = 45, border = NULL, col = NA, lty = par("lty"), ..., fillOddEven = FALSE)`

I presume I would need to change the `x` and `y` arguments in the underlying `polygon` call, but how can I do that? Can I access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are drawing the wrong plane.  The docs are a little sparse, but it appears as if `s3d$plane3d` assumes that `z` is the response variable, `x` is the first predictor, and `y` is the second one.  But even if I change your code to use those assumptions, e.g.

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(ISLR)

s3d <- with(College, scatterplot3d(z=Top10perc, x=S.F.Ratio, y=PhD))
my.lm <- lm(Top10perc ~ S.F.Ratio + PhD, data = College)
plane <- s3d$plane3d(my.lm, lty.box = "solid", draw_polygon = TRUE)
```

I don't get a good plot:

[image: screenshot]

It appears as though `scatterplot3d` isn't clipping the plane at the borders of the bounding box.

I get a better plane using `rgl`,

```
library(rgl)
library(ISLR)

with(College, plot3d(x=Top10perc, y=S.F.Ratio, z=PhD))
my.lm <- lm(Top10perc ~ S.F.Ratio + PhD, data = College)
coefs <- coef(my.lm)
planes3d(a = -1, b = coefs["S.F.Ratio"], c = coefs["PhD"], d = coefs["(Intercept)"],
         alpha = 0.2)
```

[image: screenshot]

The plot can be rotated, but doesn't look as nice as the `scatterplot3d` output (no grid on the plane), and is harder to draw:  there's no support for `lm()` results in `rgl::planes3d`, so you need to read the help page carefully.  Maybe someone else can offer a better alternative.

Comment: Correct, `z` is the response variable, thanks for noticing that. I like the second plot so I'll look into `rgl`, thanks!